# ANT - package org.testng does not exist

Tags: java, ant, testng

i have a strange problem with ant script. I have my libs (TESTNG,etc...) included as libs in my project ,also in ant script but i still get an error: package org.testng does not exist.

Here is my script

```
<project>

<property name="src.dir"   value="C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS"/>
<property name="lib.dir"   value="${src.dir}\libs"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="${src.dir}\build"/>

<presetdef name="javac">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" encoding="iso-8859-1">
    </javac>
</presetdef>

<path id="TEST.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" >
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>  
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}/*"/>
</target>

<target name="compileAll">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}\test" destdir="${build.dir}/classes">
        <classpath refid="TEST.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="${build.dir}/jar/CompiledTests.jar" basedir="${build.dir}/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.dir}"/>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="oata.MainTestRun"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/CompiledTests.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

and this is what i get from console

```
    Buildfile: C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\build\build.xml
Trying to override old definition of task javac
clean:
compileAll:
    [javac] Compiling 35 source files to C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\build\classes
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ArchiveTest.java:9: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ArchiveTest.java:10: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ArchiveTest.java:11: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\common\BaseTest.java:6: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\common\BaseTest.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\common\BaseTest.java:8: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\BasicTest.java:5: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\BasicTest.java:6: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\BasicTest.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConnectionTest.java:7: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConnectionTest.java:8: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConnectionTest.java:9: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConoTest.java:6: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConoTest.java:7: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:6: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:8: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\LicenseTest.java:14: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\LicenseTest.java:15: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\LicenseTest.java:16: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\LicenseTest.java:17: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ObjectInfoTest.java:6: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ObjectInfoTest.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ObjectInfoTest.java:8: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\OpenObjectTest.java:9: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\OpenObjectTest.java:10: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\OpenProcessListTest.java:9: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\OpenProcessListTest.java:10: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\RPCTest.java:6: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\RPCTest.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\RPCTest.java:8: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\RTITest.java:6: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\RTITest.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\SessionTest.java:7: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\SessionTest.java:8: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\StructDefInfoTest.java:6: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\StructDefInfoTest.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\TellCommandTest.java:7: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\TellCommandTest.java:8: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\TellCommandTest.java:9: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\performance\MultipleOpenObjectTest.java:5: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\performance\MultipleOpenObjectTest.java:6: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\performance\RPCMutiUserOpenTest.java:7: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\performance\RPCMutiUserOpenTest.java:8: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\MainTestRun.java:8: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\MainTestRun.java:9: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.CommandLineArgs;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\MainTestRun.java:10: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.IReporter;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\MainTestRun.java:11: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.TestNG;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\MainTestRun.java:12: error: package org.testng.xml does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\MainTestRun.java:13: error: package org.testng.xml does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\MainTestRun.java:14: error: package org.testng.xml does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;
    [javac]                      ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\MainTestRun.java:16: error: package com.beust.jcommander does not exist
    [javac] import com.beust.jcommander.JCommander;
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:6: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.ITestContext;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:7: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.ITestListener;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:8: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.ITestResult;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:9: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.TestNG;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class RPCBasicListener implements ITestListener{
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol: class ITestListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private static TestNG parentNG;
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class TestNG
    [javac]   location: class RPCBasicListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ITestResult
    [javac]   location: class RPCBasicListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ITestResult
    [javac]   location: class RPCBasicListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ITestResult
    [javac]   location: class RPCBasicListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ITestResult
    [javac]   location: class RPCBasicListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
    [javac]                                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ITestResult
    [javac]   location: class RPCBasicListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ITestContext
    [javac]   location: class RPCBasicListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicListener.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ITestContext
    [javac]   location: class RPCBasicListener
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicTest.java:6: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicTest.java:7: error: package org.testng.annotations does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\selt\tests\RPCBasicTest.java:8: error: package org.testng does not exist
    [javac] import org.testng.Assert;
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ArchiveTest.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @DataProvider(name=VALID_DATA_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider
    [javac]   location: class ArchiveTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ArchiveTest.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @DataProvider(name=INVALID_DATA_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider
    [javac]   location: class ArchiveTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ArchiveTest.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=5000, dataProvider=INVALID_DATA_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class ArchiveTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ArchiveTest.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(/*timeOut=5000,*/ dataProvider=VALID_DATA_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class ArchiveTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ArchiveTest.java:161: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(/*timeOut=8000.*/ dataProvider=VALID_DATA_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class ArchiveTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\common\BaseTest.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @BeforeClass
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BeforeClass
    [javac]   location: class BaseTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\common\BaseTest.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @AfterClass
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class AfterClass
    [javac]   location: class BaseTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\BasicTest.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class BasicTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\BasicTest.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @DataProvider(name=DEBUG_CATEGORIES_DATA_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider
    [javac]   location: class BasicTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\BasicTest.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=5000, dataProvider=DEBUG_CATEGORIES_DATA_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class BasicTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConnectionTest.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @DataProvider(name=CONNECTION_DATA_PROVIDER)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider
    [javac]   location: class ConnectionTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConnectionTest.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(dataProvider=CONNECTION_DATA_PROVIDER)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class ConnectionTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConnectionTest.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test()
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class ConnectionTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConnectionTest.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test()
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class ConnectionTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConoTest.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=8000)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class ConoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\ConoTest.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=8000)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class ConoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @DataProvider(name=COMMANDS_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider
    [javac]   location: class DebugInfoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @DataProvider(name=INVALID_COMMANDS_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class DataProvider
    [javac]   location: class DebugInfoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=5000, dataProvider=COMMANDS_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class DebugInfoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=5000, dataProvider=INVALID_COMMANDS_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class DebugInfoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:103: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=5000, dataProvider=COMMANDS_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class DebugInfoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=5000)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class DebugInfoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\DebugInfoTest.java:143: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Test(timeOut=5000, dataProvider=INVALID_COMMANDS_PROVIDER_NAME)
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Test
    [javac]   location: class DebugInfoTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests\LicenseTest.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @BeforeClass
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class BeforeClass
    [javac]   location: class LicenseTest
    [javac] C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\test\sk\ipesoft\d2000\d2japi\tests
    [javac] 100 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\GIT\SELT_jenkins_test\Java\SELT_TESTS\build\build.xml:24: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

i hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem,it was bad jar of testng ,when i use that one that is in eclipse plugin ,it work well